# In Zookeeper client how to look up offset for a group id / topic?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka

We are using Kafka 2.10 and zookeeper 3.4.
Following the info on http://kafka.apache.org/08/documentation.html#distributionimpl  I am trying to look up the offset for a group id, topic partition, but find the offset to be empty:
ls /consumers/test6/offsets/ViewerLogs/0   ---> returns []

Any suggestion how to access that value?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to connect with zookeeper cli to see what the output is? Also 2.10 is not the Kafka version, it says which version of scala this kafka is build with. The latest stable version for kafka is 0.8.1.1 (probably)

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand what you mean by "to see what the output is". Can you explain pls.   Thx

Comment: once the servie is up you can use the `ZOO_ROOT/bin.zkCli.sh` script to connect to it .. read more here https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.3/zookeeperStarted.html#sc_ConnectingToZooKeeper

Comment: Thx, but I had connected using zkCli.sh and that's how I was able to get to do "ls /consumers" and so on and so forth..... I have run a consumer with a groupid for partition 0.  Trying to see the offset that zookeeper saved from the last offset commit by my consumer. But when I do /consumers/<groupid>/offsets/<topic>/<partition> the offset value  shows as [].

Comment: shouldn't it be `/[topic]/[broker_id-partition_id]` instead [topic]/[partition_id] ?

Comment: i do ls level by level.  and when I get to ls /consumers/<groupid>/offsets/<topic> there is only one value returned and that is [0] which is the partition id (I am only owkring with 1 partition at this time).

Answer (score 4):

To get the offset value, run command get /consumers/test6/offsets/ViewerLogs/0 in zookeeper

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this document:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+data+structures+in+Zookeeper

So, the offset will be stored in Zookeeper at:

/[clusterBasePath]/consumers/[groupId]/offsets/[topic]/[partitionId] -> long (offset)

If that znode is empty, it might mean that your consumer group hasn't owned the partitions yet (decided on a mapping from partitions to consumers).

To see the current partition owners in the consumer group, take a look at:

/[clusterBasePath]/consumers/[groupId]/owners/[topic]/[partitionId] -> string (consumerId)

From personal experience, the most common cause of this is that your your consumer group is having trouble owning partitions due to timeouts. On your consumer config, you might want to try increasing rebalance.max.retries to something like 50 (or higher) and rebalance.backoff.ms to something like 5000. Also, check your Zookeeper session timeouts and increase those if necessary.

Depending on what consumer you're using (are you using consumer groups at all?), there's also a chance that you're just not committing your offsets to Zookeeper (this is ok if you don't care too much about fault tolerance). In that case, you won't be able to find the offsets in Zookeeper and will need to get them from your consumer directly.

Comment: Thx so much for the info.  I am using high level consumers with groupIds.  At this point I am not adding a consumer to an existing group. I am just trying to validate the behavior of zookeeper when starting HL consumer with a new group id.  You suggested that there is a chance that I am not commiting offsets to zzokeeper.  Do I have to code explicitly for the commiting of the offsets to the zookeeper in High Level Consumers?  Appreciate your help.

Comment: @FZF, the high level consumer should either be committing to Zookeeper, or, in newer versions of Kafka, it may be committing to the __consumer_offsets topic instead (which replaces Zookeeper for the offset storage in newer Kafka versions).